# How to automatically execute a shell command after building in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

Is it possible with Visual Studio 2005 alone?

If not with TFS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2005, right-click on your project in the Solution explorer, select properties and go to Build events and type in your command in the Post Build events.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Post-Build event for that.

It should also be possible in TFS, but which version of TFS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In the project, choose properties, and then go to "build events" and add a post-build event.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your project properties (ALT+F7)

Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Post-Build Event -> Command Line